# Why does this while loop not update my mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm still new to writing querys to mysql, so I'm sure it is a newbie mistake, but I can't figure it out.

Here is the code (with lots of echos so I can show my output):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($tempresult, MYSQL_ASSOC)){


$tempStartDate = $StartDate;
$tempEventID = $row['EventID'];
$tempDaysFromEvent = $row['DaysFromEvent'];

echo "Main Event Start Date: ".$tempStartDate."<br>";
echo "EventID: ".$tempEventID.", Start Date: ".$tempStartDate.", Days From Event: ".$tempDaysFromEvent.", Parent Event ID: ".$tempParentEventID."<br>";

$newtempStartDate = explode(" ", $tempStartDate);
echo "New Temp Start Date: ".$newtempStartDate[0];
echo "<br>";

    list($year, $month, $day) = explode("-", $newtempStartDate[0]);
echo $year." ". $month. " ". $day;
echo "<br>";
$tempStartDate  =  $tempEndDate =  date("Y-m-d", mktime(0,0,0,$month,($day+$tempDaysFromEvent),$year)) . " 00:00:00";
echo "TempStart Date:".$tempStartDate."<br>";

mysql_query("UPDATE".$eventDatabase." SET StartDate='$tempStartDate',EndDate='$tempEndDate'where EventID ='$tempEventID'");

    error_reporting(E_ALL);


}
```

Here is my output:

```
Main Event Start Date: 2011-07-04 15:00:00
EventID: 4876, Start Date: 2011-07-04 15:00:00, Days From Event: 4, Parent Event ID: 4865
New Temp Start Date: 2011-07-04
2011 07 04
TempStart Date:2011-07-08 00:00:00
```

The output looks correct to me-it looks like I want it to look in the db.  I don't know if the issue is because $tempStartDate is a string?  It is a datetime in mysql, but that shouldn't matter I don't think??

Comment: are you getting any mysql errors? I can see you're missing some spaces in your query: `mysql_query("UPDATE ".$eventDatabase." SET StartDate='$tempStartDate', EndDate='$tempEndDate' where EventID ='$tempEventID'");`

Comment: Always do `mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error());`, especially during development. Dirk's got the solution: you've got a bad query with syntax errors, and doing the `or die()` would've shown it to you immediately.

Comment: Please post the query as output from echo so we can see whether the variables are parsed correctly etc. Additionally you can use or die(mysql_error()) to get an error if the query is wrong

Comment: I'm not-which is what is confusing me.

Comment: Hey-great-those spaces were my problem.  AND thanks for showing me the correct formatting for getting the errors!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comment above, it appears that you are missing spaces in your SQL statement.  Replace your `mysql_query()` call with this:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE $eventDatabase SET StartDate='$tempStartDate', EndDate='$tempEndDate' WHERE EventID='$tempEventID'");
```

When in doubt, you can always assign the SQL query to a string variable first, and echo the string so that you can see the full SQL statement, including variable values.

Answer (score 2):

Try echoing the actual sql command.  Looks like you need a space there after the "UPDATE" and before 'where EventID= xxx";

Try and execute the actual output from echo in SQL admin page.